# Automatically detecting possible `UnboundLocalError`s

Tags: python, static-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
def main():
    if 2 == 3:
        a = 3
    print(a)

main()
```

When run, it's going to crash with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. Despite that, `pylint` doesn't warn me there's a possible path in which `a` is not going to be set. Is there way to automatically check my code against such cases?

Comment: Why would you put the docstring _above_ the function?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix just to silence one pylint warning. Original version didn't use a function at all, but then I discovered that it throws a different exception then.

Answer (score 1):

When I typed this into Pycharm, i got yellow underlining that read "Code is unreachable"
I do not have any plugins installed, so whatever the default linting program for Pycharm is catching it.

Update #1

Ill just point out that I have professional version of Pycharm.

Comment: Interesting - it evaluated the case. Still, if you made it any bit more complex (like evaluating a function call that just returns False), would it still catch it?

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't worry about whether or not a branch will actually run, just check if all paths before that have some way of assigning to the variable